# How to include database file as part of your project in iOS which is located at path Library/..Applications/../dbfile.sqlite on my mac

Tags: ios, iphone

My database file is located at Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/../dbfile.sqlite on my mac.
How do i include this database file with my project to run it on iPhone .Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the file to your project. Open the right side panel and make sure the file is included in your target. Even go to the Copy build phase for the target and verify that it's going to get copied. Now that file can be found in you apps bundle.